# Swagger How to enable Filter by tag as case insensitive

Tags: filter, tags, swagger, case-insensitive, springfox

I am using Swagger-UI implemented through Springfox 2.9.2.

I have enabled "Filter By tag" by setting "filter" as true in UiConfiguration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import({BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class})
//https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    .
    .
    .

    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()
            .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.MODEL)
            .defaultModelsExpandDepth(-1)
            .displayRequestDuration(true)
            .displayOperationId(false)
            .filter(true)
            .deepLinking(true).build();
    }
}
```

But this filter is case sensitive. I need to search without case condition..

How can i make this Tag Filter case insensitive..?

[image]

Comment: There is an issue raised against this feature: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3876